# calibre does not start - Python error _Py_FatalErrorFunc

Tags: debian, kde, calibre

#### Background

Debian testing (bullseye) kernel 5.9.0, KDE, calibre 5.5.0

#### Symptoms

Calibre does not start, not even its GUI appears. Console shows a Python-related error message about `_Py_FatalErrorFunc`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to update Calibre to a version newer than in `testing`. There are two alternatives:

1. As per [Calibre author response to a user of Kali Linux](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=335081), you could remove the Calibre shipped in your distribution and [install directly from Calibre website](https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux). I did not follow this advice as I prefer to leverage Debian's packaging system as much as possible.
2. Install an updated version from `unstable` or `experimental` Debian distributions

I took option 2. Mixing packages from various distributions is discouraged. Using anything from `experimental` is [discouraged even more](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianExperimental). But sometimes the program you've been running regularly fails and you need a fix quickly. I don't think falling back on option 1 is the best choice in the long run.

[Debian package search](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_packages) showed that although `Calibre` is not available in `experimental`, a version slightly newer to mine exists in `unstable` (codenamed `sid`).

#### Add `unstable` as possible source of packages

Create a file

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unstable.list
```

and paste

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
```

#### (optional) Add `experimental` as possible source of packages

Create a file

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/experimental.list
```

and paste

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian experimental main contrib non-free
```

#### Update Calibre

Resynchronize package index

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then `s`imulate what `apt-get` would do

```
sudo apt-get -st unstable install calibre
```

then, if you consider the extent of required updates safe, issue the command without `s` to do the actual update

```
sudo apt-get -t unstable install calibre
```

Once you're done, edit `unstable.list` and put `#` at the beginning of the entry to comment it out. Otherwise `apt` will take these unstable versions into account at next `upgrade`. Run `sudo apt-get update` to resynchronize package index again. Commenting out is not necessary for `experimental` because of `apt`'s package prioritization default settings.

Although getting anything from `experimental` is not needed in this case, it may be useful in the future. For example, to get the latest `nvidia-driver` package, you'd use `sudo apt-get -t experimental install nvidia-driver`.

The `t` option tells `apt` to **temporarily** prioritize (for this call only) package versions from the given release. `Experimental` [is not a full distribution](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianExperimental), it is an extension of `unstable`.

Comment: For this particular case, where installing a couple packages (calibre and calibre-bin) is enough and you did the work to find out Sid's packages work, I'd rather download the packages directly: https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/calibre/download, https://packages.debian.org/sid/calibre-bin (on the second link, per-architecture package downloads are at the bottom)